# Interior hand railing paint not drying

Tags: paint

I just painted my metal interior handrail with krypton water based paint. The banister has not been painted in 10 years but could have been painted with oil base paint. The new paint is tacky after two days will it ever dry?

Comment: How thick were your coats and how many did you apply.   On metal, several very very thin coats works best IME

Answer (score 1):

Sure it will dry.  I will not bind right because you missed the step of using a primer.   You are going to have to strip it no matter what.   If it is still "wettish" and a lot of the paint comes off with a putty knife, try to get as much as possible now.

You are looking at using some sort of paint solvent (thinner) or sanding.   There is no fixing this, just a learning experience.